# Speakers don't work on Asus ROG Strix G16 G614JV in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, asus, speakers

Some days ago I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in dual boot on an Asus Rog Strix G16 G614JV, but the speakers don't work.

I've followed some guides like this: https://devicetests.com/asus-rog-strix-g15-no-sound-issue-ubuntu but nothing has worked for me.

Has anyone managed to solve it?

This is the output of the command:

```
alfarrow@alfarrow:~$ journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"

oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: cs35l41-hda spi1-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: Error: ACPI _DSD Properties are missing for HID CSC3551.
oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: cs35l41-hda spi1-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: error -EINVAL: Platform not supported
oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: cs35l41-hda: probe of spi1-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0 failed with error -22
oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: cs35l41-hda spi1-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1: Error: ACPI _DSD Properties are missing for HID CSC3551.
oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: cs35l41-hda spi1-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1: error -EINVAL: Platform not supported
oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: cs35l41-hda: probe of spi1-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1 failed with error -22
oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Applying patch firmware 'hda-jack-retask.fw'
oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Applying patch firmware 'hda-jack-retask.fw'
oct 15 20:04:49 alfarrow kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input24
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input25
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input26
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input27
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC294: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x19
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Headset Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input35
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input36
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input37
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input38
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input39
oct 15 20:04:50 alfarrow kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input40
```

Comment: Attach the output of this command: `journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, the output is too long so I have attached it to my first message.

Comment: Kernel 6.5.0 also works, but nvidia doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel 6.5.0 also works, but nvidia doesn't work there.

Update ubuntu 22.4 kernel 6.5.18  pach

```
DefinitionBlock ("", "SSDT", 1, "CUSTOM", "CSC3551", 0x00000001)
{
    External (_SB_.PC00.SPI3, DeviceObj)
    External (_SB_.PC00.SPI3.SPK1, DeviceObj)

    Scope (_SB.PC00.SPI3.SPK1)
    {
        Name (_DSD, Package ()   // _DSD: Device-Specific Data
        {
            ToUUID ("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
            Package ()
            {
                Package () { "cirrus,dev-index", Package () { Zero, One }},
                Package () { "reset-gpios", Package () {
                                        SPK1, One, Zero, Zero,
                                        SPK1, One, Zero, Zero,
                } },
                Package () { "spk-id-gpios", Package () {
                                        SPK1, 0x02, Zero, Zero,
                                        SPK1, 0x02, Zero, Zero,
                } },
                Package () { "cirrus,speaker-position",     Package () { Zero, One } },
                // gpioX-func: 0 not used, 1 VPSK_SWITCH, 2: INTERRUPT, 3: SYNC
                Package () { "cirrus,gpio1-func",           Package () { One, One } },
                Package () { "cirrus,gpio2-func",           Package () { 0x02, 0x02 } },
                // boost-type: 0 internal, 1 external
                Package () { "cirrus,boost-type",           Package () { One, One } },
            },
        })
    }

    Scope (_SB.PC00.SPI3)
    {
        Name (_DSD, Package ()
        {
            ToUUID ("daffd814-6eba-4d8c-8a91-bc9bbf4aa301"),
            Package ()
            {
                Package () { "cs-gpios", Package () {
                    Zero,                    // Native CS
                    SPK1, Zero, Zero, Zero   // GPIO CS
                } }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

worked !